# Getting cached page even if I have no cache

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, caching

I have a page with a button which opens a popup where you can input text in to a input  field, this data can be posted then it will save the data in mysql database. After closing the popup I will call a php file which selects this newly added data from the database and then append it to the page and delete the row from database. After doing this again i see the old data, i also used no cache on the main page but no use:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); // sometimes it's needed when overridden to Off
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.

session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedInToProcurement'] = 'yes';
$uniquekey = "1337";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```